# Does Informix have scheduled triggers?

Tags: stored-procedures, triggers, scheduled-tasks, informix

I need an Informix database to update some records on December 31 at 11:59; can Informix do this on a trigger, or does it have a scheduler of some sorts?

I'm an Informix noob btw.

I'm using informix 11.1 for hp-ux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have Informix 11.10 or later, then there is a [task scheduler facility](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.admin.doc/ids_admin_1121.htm) built into IDS.  The search term 'scheduler' in the [Knowledge Center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.welcome.doc/welcome.htm) leads you to relevant information.

If you have earlier versions of IDS, then the facility is missing and you should upgrade to get it if it is important to you to have it.

---

*When asking questions about Informix, please provide the version of Informix (at least to the 11.50 level of detail, preferably to the 11.50.FC3 detail) and the platform where you are running it (operating system and version number - and sometimes chip type). This should be automatic when asking questions about Informix products.  (And this is a general comment, not solely aimed at you.)*

Comment: Note that you could use 'cron' to run a task at a scheduled time as an alternative to using the DBMS scheduler - or if your version of IDS does not have the scheduler.  Also, was your question asking for 11:59 or 23:59?  Beware of granularity in scheduled times; check how reliably the scheduler launches tasks at a given time, especially if '11:59' is really '23:59' and it is crucial that it complete (or, at least, starts) before midnight.  It shouldn't be a problem, but...better safe than sorry.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Server Studio you can set jobs using Sentinel.